# Should I use "grid connectivity" or "grid connectivities"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I am confused whether I should use connectivity or connectivities in the following sentence:

> This processor analyzes the statuses of various switches and circuit-breakers in
>   the system and determines the grid **connectivity** among different electrical nodes (i.e., buses).

Comment: Why are you using "statuses"?

Comment: Also, how many different connectivities are being determined? Is it one overall connectivity?

Comment: Are you sure "connectivity" is the right word in the first place? In an earthbound electrical system (as opposed to the internet) would not the more definite word "connections" be better?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend *Connectivities* as you're referring to multiple mappings between multiple nodes.

*Connectivity* would have been more appropriate, had you not introduced the qualifying phrase : *among the different nodes* and word *statuses*. At various points in that sentence, you're taking several plural forms into account. You should use *Connectivities* to consummate the multiples you're alluding to in your sentence